# Div height issues ,div get collapsed in ie and firefox

Tags: html, struts2, cross-browser

I have a wrapper div in my page ,which is having rows of data.I haven't set any height to this div,as it should vary the size , with the change in the content.This div  works fine with chrome.The problem is that  in IE and Firefox   div get collapsed . I have noticed , firefox and IE are giving a particular height to the div.But there is no such issue with chrome.Please suggest a solution.....
Any help is appreciated....

The  code I am  using is attached

```
            <div id="list" class="roundBox" style="">
                <s:bean name="java.util.HashMap" id="qTableLayout">
                    <s:param name="tablecolspan" value="%{8}" />
                </s:bean>
                <table class="list">
                    <s:hidden name="selector"/>
                    <tr>
                        <th >row 1</th>
                        <th >row 2</th>
                        <th >row 3</th>
                        <th >row 4</th>
                        <th >row 5</th>
                        <th class="currency" >row 6</th>
                        <th>row 7</th>
                        <th>row 8</th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                    <s:iterator value="logList">
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:property value="channelId"/></td>
                        <td><s:date format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" name="requestReceiveTime"/></td>
                        <td><s:date format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" name="processBeginTime"/></td>
                        <td><s:date format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" name="processEndTime"/></td>
                        <td><s:date format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" name="responseAccessTime"/></td>
                        <td class="currency"><s:property value="responseTime"/></td>
                        <td>[<s:property value="responseCode"/>] <s:property value="responseDesc"/></td>

                        <td>

                        <sx:a  
                            href="showchannel?channelId=%{channelId}&token=%{token}" 
                            onclick="javascript:showDropdown('%{token}','show');" executeScripts="true" targets="%{token}channel" 
                            title="View Channel Information" id="%{token}showlink"><img src="images/tree_closed.gif"/></sx:a>
                        <a href=javascript:showDropdown('<s:property value="token"/>','hide'); title="Show/Hide Details" id="<s:property value="token"/>hidelink" style="display:none;"><img src="images/tree_open.gif"/></a>


                        </td>
                        <td>
                        <sx:a 
                            href="audittrailchannel?channelId=%{channelId}&token=%{token}" 
                            onclick="javascript:showauditDropdown('%{token}','show');"
                            executeScripts="true" targets="%{token}auditchannel" title="View Audit Information" 
                            id="%{token}showauditlink"><img src="images/down.png" /></sx:a>
                        <a href=javascript:showauditDropdown('<s:property value="token"/>','hide'); title="Show/Hide Details" id="<s:property value="token"/>hideauditlink" style="display:none;"><img src="images/up.png" /></a>
                        </td>
                        </tr>


                        <tr id="<s:property value="token"/>dropdown" style="display: none">
                            <td colspan="9" valign="top" bgcolor="#a4a4a4">

                                <table class="reports_details" style="width:100%;" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffe2">
                                    <tr><td colspan="3" style="height: 10px">
                                    <sx:div id="%{token}channel">

                                    </sx:div>
                            </td></tr>
                        <tr>

                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><s:date format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" name="requestReceiveTime"/></td>
                        <td>channel request</td>
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showPopup('<s:property value="token"/>Request')">[View]</a></td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td><s:date format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" name="responseAccessTime"/></td>
                        <td>channel response</td>
                        <td><a href="#" onclick="showPopup('<s:property value="token"/>Response')">[View]</a></td>
                        </tr>


                        <s:iterator value="serverLogList">
                            <tr>
                                <td><s:date format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" name="requestTime"/></td>
                            <td><s:property value="requestType"/></td>
                            <td><a href="#" onClick="showPopup('<s:property value="serverLogId"/>ServerLog')">[View]</a></td>
                            </tr>


                        </s:iterator>


                </table></td>

            </tr>
            <tr id="<s:property value="token"/>auditdropdown" style="display: none;">
                <td colspan="9" valign="top" bgcolor="#a4a4a4">
            <sx:div id="%{token}auditchannel" cssStyle="height:100px;overflow:scroll"></sx:div>
            </td>
            </tr>

            </s:iterator>
            <s:if test="logList.size() >= 1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdLabel" colspan="9"><center><s:a href ='javascript: submitPrev()' > << Previous </s:a><s:property value="pageIndex"/> of <s:property value="pageCount"/><s:a href ='javascript: submitNext()' > Next >> </s:a></center></td>

                </tr>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                <tr><td>No records found</td></tr>
            </s:else>


            </table>

            </div>
```

Comment: You will have to set overflow:auto or overflow:hidden

Comment: please share your markup or make a fiddle for us to fix your error

Answer (score 0):

What did you put in your div? 
In standard html empty div tags are not rendered even if you have a style with any width/height on it.
Show us the code if my answer don't help so we can see what it is wrong.

Comment: I have added the code....

The div is having rows of data which uses an <s:iterator> to iterate a  list and on the basis of that iteration data is displayed.On each row there is an image on clicking on that image will expand ,  to show more info on that row.The Div  get collapsed  on clicking on the image, as the height of the div changes.This problem happens only on firefox and IE and works fine with chrome.

Comment: Did you try set overflow:auto on your class? And do you have any other content that "steal" the height on resize events so there is no space left (Try set a height for testing)?

Comment: ..Thanks for your quick response..
actually I  tried  overflow:auto ,now the div is not collapsing, and its shown  with scroll bars.But I would like to produce the same effect as how seen on chrome.Is there any way for that....

Comment: Actually is hard to give tips here, but it seems you have problems getting the correct height of you surrounding div tag on a resize event. Did you tried height:auto or 100%, overflow:none ? Standard html and height 100% is tricky, so create a test page with your basic layout where you have different content sizes. Your table content is "just any content", so focus on the resize thing. BTW: Render the page and use firebug to manipulate the CSS styles directly on the rendered page, much faster way to solve style render problems.